# Mysql creating an Event that updates something every monday, friday and sunday for ever

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

Do you guys have any idea of how to do this in Mysql?? to Create only one event without using 'IF' that happens how many days i want forever? 
Ex: an Event that happens every mondey, friday and sunday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any syntax for what you're describing.

If I had to do this with a MySQL EVENT, I'd implement this with an `IF` for the day of week (MySQL uses Sunday=1).

```
CREATE EVENT MyEvent
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO BEGIN
  IF DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) IN (1, 2, 6) THEN
    ...whatever you want...
  END IF
END
```

But practically speaking, I don't use MySQL EVENTs. I use `cron`. Then one can specify to run on the three days of the week you want (cron uses Sunday=0):

```
0 0 * * 0,1,5 myscript.sh
```

Comment: What is the issue to use MySQL events over cron?